# How to deal with a recruiter who pushes me to attend an interview?

Tags: recruitment

I received a call from recruitment agency. The recruiter told me there is job vacancy and will pass my resume to company.

After some weeks, received a call from agency to schedule an interview.  I did some research, saw it was the IT industry, and I told the recruiter I wouldn't be going to the interview.  (I'm not interested in IT)

He messaged and asked me if another date would work and gave me options for other dates. I told him I'd decide later and tell him. He repeatedly messaged me and asking for a decision. When i didn't reply he called multiple times, even at 9+ at night. To stop him I told one date which is Friday.

He called the next day as well. I blocked him as he was not listening to me.

As the interview date approached, he kept on calling and messaging, but I blocked him. Then he messaged from another number and was angry that I did not respond and he demanded to know why.  I said I got another job and blocked.

How could I have more effectively communicated my non-interest, and how could I have better handled his pushy attitude?

Comment: If I'm reading this right, it sounds like there was some urgency in filling the role. As you initially said you would 'decide later', is it possible the recruiter did not interpret that as a definite "No"? Did you make it clear later that you were absolutely not interested?

Comment: I told him i am not attending the interview. But he insisted me to tell him another date which i can attended. For that i told him already an going overseas and took leave. So i can't take more any. He have 2 dates 30th and 31st and told me to choose one when i already told him am not free.when i didn't reply he kept on calling me and he even called at 9pm. which agency will call at 9pm?

Comment: There are several problems with your question. Please take a few minutes and have a look at the [help henter](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help) to see [what topics](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) you can ask about and what [topics to avoid](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Also please keep in mind to ask only one specific question that can have one specific answer. Asking for peoples oppinions is off topic on this site.

Comment: Why can't you just say, "No, thanks. I'm not interested??" It's unclear why you're constantly giving him the runaround. This entire problem is stemmed from trying to communicate something you do not want.

Comment: @meena Just don't show up. Tell him you're not interested and you will not be going to the interviews. Make it very clear, and state only in a single sentence. "I am not interested in the IT industry and do not want to go to any interviews. Please cancel these days as I will not be attending. Thank you."

Answer (score 9):

Arranging an interview and not showing up for it, or telling someone you'll "decide later" and hope they stop bothering are both habits that won't serve you well in your career.

Additionally, you should instruct the recruiter to pass on your CV **after** you've done some research on the company, not before. Telling someone to go ahead and then pulling out because you don't like the industry is an unnecessary waste of everyone's time.

The best play would've been to escalate to the recruiter's boss. If even that doesn't do it, I would even go as far as contacting their client company to let them know what's going on.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than telling the recruiter

> I'm not attending the interview

Maybe you should have tried

> I'm not interested in working for X company, so won't be attending the interview

Being honest and open can go a long way.  Even if you think you were clear, others might not see what you actually mean.

On [@rath](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/9549/rath)'s point about checking out the company first, while this is something you should definitely do, it appears from your description that the recruiter didn't give you much choice/time to back out or express a lack of interest before they sent of your CV, so I think they are at fault here. Maybe this is something worth raising with your recruitment agency for when future opportunities come up.

Comment: `the recruiter didn't give you much choice/time` Agreed. Getting information out of recruiters is a skill if they decide to be reticent. But you always have the upper hand because recruiters are a dime a dozen. Even if they refuse to give info about the role, just say _No thanks_ and they'll come around after a while on their own.

Comment: @rath From an objective standpoint you're completely correct, but people who don't know that, when put on the spot would not want to let the 'opportunity' slip by

Comment: I refuse to work with anyone that cannot tell me whom I might be working for, before, I even entertain an interview.  I have been burned by the cold call recruiters far too many times.

Answer (score 1):

Next time, simply tell the recruiter as soon as there is a change of any sort.  You don't have to deal with a pushy recruiter if you say

> sorry, I'm no longer interested

and leave it at that. If he persists, and demands to know why say:

> I'm sorry, mu reasons are personal and I cannot discuss them.

Be upfront and honest in all of your dealings or it will come back to haunt you as you found out.  Recruiters are paid by the placement and he was likely irritated over the fact that he invested so much time negotiating on your behalf only to get ghosted by you.

**IN THE FUTURE**

Say "I'm not interested".  The pushiness will stop right there and then.  The recruiter will move on to another candidate.  He isn't going to bother you if he doesn't see a payoff in his future.